# Laravel file size validation returns error regardless of file size

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate a submitted file using a validator:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate(['profilePhoto' => 'required|image|size:256']);
```

However regardless of the size of the file I try to submit, be it 3MB or 50KB it always returns the same error: `{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"profilePhoto":["The profile photo must be 256 kilobytes."]}}`.
My php settings: `post_max_size: 64M` and `upload_max_filesize: 64M`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> size:value => The field under validation must have a size matching the given value.

Use `max` instead of `size`

```
$validatedData = $request->validate(['profilePhoto' => 'required|image|max:256']);
```

Note that the value is in kilobytes. I.e. max:10240 = max 10 MB.

Comment: Docs to expand on this answer: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-size

Answer (score 0):

"profilePhoto" => 'required|.....|max:200'

200 in kilobytes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: max take number in kilobytes .

Answer (score -1):

Edit your size:256 to 256000 which is shown as below should fix the problem.

```
$validatedData = $request->validate(['profilePhoto' => 'required|image|size:256000']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I actually tried that. Same problem, it says `The profile photo must be 256000 kilobytes.`